# Units without maintenance cost

Tags: civilization-5, mods

In my current game, under *Economic Overview*, it's mentioned that I "own 3 units that do not require maintenance."

I'm using the *Communitas AI&Tools* and *Interface* mods. Not sure is they made the info available or if it's in vanilla as well.

Factors:

1. Built Pyramids (2 free workers)
2. Policy: Liberty -> Citizenship (1 worker 'appears')
3. Liberated 1 worker from barbarians and did not return to Denmark

Total number of suspects: 4

I do not have the Oligarchy policy from the Tradition tree, so it's not from units garrisoned in cities that cost no maintenance.

Which of these (or the other) units are usually maintenance-free? And is there any way to find out which ones walking around, say, 1 of 6 workers, is the cheap one? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the source of your three free units.

The **Honor Tree**'s *Military Caste*: 3 units cost no maintenance (in addition to garrison bonuses).

After some digging through *Communitas*'s patch-notes documentation I found this [page](https://github.com/Thalassicus/cep-bnw/releases) which contained the information.
This is the only maintenance-free changes I could manage to find in all of the documentation that I searched on the *Communitas* site.

Comment: I'm not using the Communitas Enhancements. Only the AI and Interface packs. All units, policies, buildings, etc. are vanilla, so it can't be because of Military Caste (also because I don't have the policy in the first place ;) ) I'll check to see what the game currently says.

Comment: Do you have any ideologies? Off the top of my head I'm not sure which one (I'll look it up if your answer is yes) but one of the (maybe more) give free unit maintenance.

Comment: Nah, it was earlier in the game. There is indeed a tenet that gives 6 units maintenance-free. Still haven't gotten around to checking the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use this Communitas mod (i don't use any) but i have the same message. So i don't think this answer is right.
After my own search, i found that maintenance free units are: Cargo Ships, Caravans, and Guided Missiles.